# What is the intended way to test a Material-UI Menu component using React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am developing an app which already makes extensive use of React Testing Library.

We are adding new components utilizing Material-UI however it seems in many cases these components are not testable using this framework.

Here is one example I can provide of a test which breaks for no clear reason.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-menu-test-uik0w

After searching around it seems like, in general, many folks are experiencing issues using these two libraries together and I would like to start a discussion on how we might be able to move forward.

Comment: I recommend you look at the tests in Material-UI itself since they have migrated many of their tests (including [integration tests](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.0/packages/material-ui/test/integration/Menu.test.js) of `Menu`) to use [React Testing Library](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.0/test/utils/createClientRender.js#L11).

Comment: I do see the tests you've linked to but I suppose I am still not quite understanding what they are doing differently. I have attempted to use their `createClientRender` script as a replacement for `@testing-library/react` but I still run into many issues.

Is there some additional configuration they are using which I could take a closer look at?

Comment: Here would be the same example from above but using `createClientRender`

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-menu-test-with-createclientrender-imgch

Comment: I can work around the particular error in your sandbox ("Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.") by specifying the container for the `Menu` (https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-menu-test-to1no). I'm not saying this is what you should do, but it might help with understanding the problem better. The [code being executed in the error case](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.0/packages/material-ui/src/Modal/ModalManager.js#L72) only happens in very specific conditions.

Comment: Okay! That does fix this particular error and I am able to click on my Menu Button and render/query for the MenuItems. I appreciate your comments greatly @RyanCogswell